# How to make a For Each loop in SSRS Charts

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm making a charts in SSRS that will display the absence ration per department 
so in the chart Data ( Values field ) I have the following expression :

```
=Sum(Fields!Absence_Hours.Value, "DataSet1") / 
  Sum(Fields!Worked_Hours.Value, "DataSet1")
```

This expression works fine when I have only one department chosen, but once I choose more than one department, the program does the following:

```
(total absence hours of all chosen departments ) / 
 (total worked hours of all chosen departments )
```

This returns a single value which makes all my department have the same value in the charts.

How can I make the expression above execute and return results for each department ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a for each loop. Drag and drop your department field into the chart datas **Category Groups** section.

This way the calculation gets done per department in the chart.